# is there a proper way to copy char pointer array to char pointer array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char, copy

I've made a function like this:

```
void AddVariantItem(char *displayText, char **optionstext)<
```

so that I can place a char pointer array in the function like:

```
char *array[] = { "test" };
AddVariantItem("test", array);
```

I'm saving the array inside of the function for later use by using

```
menuItem.optionstext = optionstext;
```

I'm copying the char to a char pointer I'm using like (outside out of the function)

```
sprintf_s(newDisplayText, sizeof(newDisplayText), "%s: < %s >", menuItem->vartext, menuItem->optionstext);
```

When i use the 'sprint' above, I crash, and it's because of the`menuItem->optionstext`

Is there a proper way to copy the char pointer array into the variable I'm trying to save it to? the optionstext is defined as char **optionstext; in a struct I've made

Comment: Why not use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: use string to define it to start off with or to copy it? I need to use char pointer arrays for what I'm doing

Comment: Why do you need to use char pointer arrays?  `std::string` is meant to represent strings and IMHO is a lot easier to deal with.

Comment: I'm using them so that I can put an unlimited amount of char pointers into one function parameter without having to add more parameters every time i want to add another string

Comment: What is `newDisplayText`? To use `menuItem->optionstext` with `sprintf_s` you need to index into it  `menuItem->options text[n]`. You have not indicated how you manage or know the size of `char **optionstext`, how do you keep a record of the size of the `char*` array? *Is there a proper way to copy the char pointer array into the variable* - probably with a `for` loop and `strcpy_s`, but there is too little code to say, try create a [mcve] to demonstrate the actual code.

Comment: @MCDOOGLEye *I'm using them so that I can put an unlimited amount of char pointers* -- Use `std::vector<std::string>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is either use `std::vector` or that sort of container for management- because the failure point of your design is that you are trying to copy into an un-allocated space.

If you don't use an allocated-storage helper (like containers in stl etc.) you have to manage your own allocation-deallocation scheme for such lists of objects and it is quite tedious to implement (especially if you are not careful, problematic even) and most of the time unnecessary - as the containers are quite good at their job.

Use `std::vector<std::string>` or that sort for those menu options; and then you can even use trivial operators like assignment operator (=) which are already well implemented in those containers and you'll be grand :)